# HTTPRestponse не возвращает числа

Tags: ajax, django

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с немного забавной ситуацией: отправляю на сервер AJAX-ом запрос и в отчете мне надо вернуть одно число:

def ToFriend(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    user_id = request.POST.get("id",'')
    user = Profile.objects.get(id=user_id)
    print user_id
    return HttpResponse(user_id)
```

Как вы поняли - это user_id. Так вот, как я не пытался, даже `HttpResponse(str(user_id))` - получаю пустой ответ. При этом user_id - это число, в консоль выводится нормальное число. С чем это может быть связано?

Забавно, что если я добавлю к числу непустую строку: `HttpResponse(str(user_id) + "__")`, то получаю нормальный ответ в виде 'моечисло__', например, '6__'

Comment: Где и как вы проверяете ответ?

Comment: @andreymal, ловлю ответ внутри onreadystatechange: `if (this.readyState == 3) alert('responseText: ' + this.responseText );`

Comment: При readyState=3 responseText содержит лишь **частичные** данные. Замените на 4 и попробуйте ещё раз

Comment: @andreymal, вот кстати опять столкнулся с этим моментом. На `readyState=4` заменил - то же самое. Но! Я обнаружил, что дело не в числах, а в длине строки. Почему-то возвращает пустую строку, если длина строки меньше двух символов. Добавляю 3-й - все отлично возвращается. Парадокс